# Не получается программно вывести в TextArea текст

Tags: java, javafx

контроллер

```
@FXML
private static TextArea terminal;


public static TextArea getTerminal() {
    return terminal;
}
```

и где метод должен объявляться

```
getTerminal().setText(name + "Соединение установлено");
```

В итоге вылезает ошибка

```
Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TextArea.setText(String)" because the return value of "project.trojanmanager.controllers.ControllerManagerApp.getTerminal()" is null
```

Как я понимаю данные теряются

Как это исправить?

Comment: Создать нужно экземпляр `terminal`.

Comment: Ну,  создал. так же null

Comment: FX фреймворк не инициализирует статичные поля. TextArea terminal должен быть нестатичным

Comment: @Maxim static я убрал. Всё равно  не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Следующий метод больше подходит для создания модели,
нежели для контроллера.
Это метод для получения объекта TextArea,
а не для работы с его текстом.
*/
public static TextArea getTerminal() {
    return terminal;
}
```

Для работы с простым TextArea нет необходимости в создании модели (отдельного класса, объявляющего объект со всеми его переменными), можно обойтись и следующими командами:

```
terminal.getText();//для получения текста из элемента
terminal.setText("");//для присвоение элементу текста
```

Чтобы работать с TextArea из другого класса, необходимо:

1. сделать TextArea
   публичным:

   @FXML
   public TextArea terminal;

Вариант 1:

2. импортировать класс, где он объявлен

   import путь.к.файлу.класс; (путь объявляется от дочерней папки src)
3. работать с terminal через импортированный класс

   класс.terminal.setText("");

Вариант 2 (если из класса нужен только TextArea):

2. импортировать класс, где он объявлен, вместе с переменной

   import путь.к.файлу.класс.terminal;
3. работать с terminal

   terminal.setText("");

Comment: Так мне надо что бы текст в TextArea вывелся в другом классе. и надо как то terminal объявить в этом же другом классе

Comment: Ответ я поменяла. Он Вам подходит?